# Php: spotify playback track using PUT curl

Tags: php, curl, spotify

In the Spotify documentation, it indicates that it is possible to send the instructions to play the song.

[Documentation here](https://developer.spotify.com/console/put-play/?device_id=&body=%7B%22uris%22%3A%5B%22spotify%3Atrack%3A7fODjB7BrQTGqh0hogW6XD%22%5D%7D)

He tried to transfer this to php but did not respond to the request.
I don't know what I will do wrong, I hope to solve this problem.

**This my request body**

```
{
  "uris": [
    "spotify:track:7fODjB7BrQTGqh0hogW6XD"
  ]
}
```

From the web it works, but in php I can't send the request.

```
{ "error": { "status": 401, "message": "Invalid access token" } }
```

**This is my php code [UPDATED - 2019/11/8]**

```
function sendTrack($token){    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play' );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(['uris' => ['spotify:track:7fODjB7BrQTGqh0hogW6XD']]));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Authorization: Bearer '.$token.'')); 

    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    echo $result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CURL_POSTFIELDS are in wrong format. Try this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(['uris' => ['spotify:track:7fODjB7BrQTGqh0hogW6XD']]);
```

Edit: 
Also according to spotify documentation you need to send a PUT request so instead of

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           1 );
```

try

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
```

**Edit2:**
just tried this code and it works, only creating error that no active device was found which im sure happened because i missed a step or two.

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play' );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(['uris' => ['spotify:track:7fODjB7BrQTGqh0hogW6XD']]));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: json', 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token));

    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    echo $result;
```

Comment: I tried but I still get this error: { "error": { "status": 401, "message": "Invalid access token" } }

Comment: Okay, according to spotify documentation https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/start-a-users-playback/ you need to use PUT method
I updated my original answer with how to do it

Comment: I receive the same error, the token is correct since it shows me the playlist. What could it be?

Comment: Updated my question, try edit2, it was working for me, or else, i didnt get the invalid token message

Comment: I copied exactly but it still returns the same error. :(

Comment: Try `var_dump(array('Content-Type: json', 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token));` and compare it with your actual token. It has to be wrong

Comment: Sorry, I was passing the code like a token. Now I receive this error: {
  "error" : {
    "status" : 401,
    "message" : "Permissions missing"
  }
}

Comment: You need to have `user-modify-playback-state` authorization scope enabled. Check this article on authorization https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/